# UIInterfaceOrientation rotation in subview not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, subview, uiinterfaceorientation, uiwindow

In my App I use a UITabbarController, which rotates perfectly to all UIInterfaceOrientations in all viewcontrollers. But when I add an UIView to the UIWindow afterwards it will not be added in the current UIInterfaceOrientation, but always in UInterfaceOrientationPortrait (which is default for the app). It won't rotate to a new orientation also. I add the ViewController by using:

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:[loginViewController view]];
```

I have

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"YES IT WILL!");
}
```

in LoginViewController.m but there will never be logged anything. Any idea why the subview won't rotate?

SideSwipe

EDIT:
Found the solution:
Apparently UIWindow should only have one subview, not more, otherwise things will mess up, so i call:

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
```

instead, which will autorotate the loginviewcontrollers view just fine.

Comment: +1 Your answer is what i needed all along± my views were acting up SOOO MUCH it was unbelievable. i tried posting user interface orientation notifications delegates passing through user interface orientations it was crazy. present modal view controller is exactly what i needed. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a view inside another view, when rotation happened, only the parent `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` got called, so what I did is add `[self.subViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];` to parent's `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.

Comment: This seems to be a bit dirtier solution plus in my example there are two subviews of uiwindow, and only one of them behaves correctly :) thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding a new subview to window, you have to make the window rotate too.

Comment: how am i supposed to do this?
the uitabbarcontrollers view is added to the uiwindow with exactly the same style:
'[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];'
and autorotating works flawlessly with it, without doing something special to rotate the window

Comment: Firstly, initialise your view with nib name,LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nameOfXIB" bundle:nil];
[self.window addSubview:[loginViewController view]]; And check, if rotation is working properly or not

Comment: Why should I init it with an NIB? Anyhow, found the soulution myself. Look at edit.

Comment: Just to answer your question, Why one should initWithNibName...There are two mutually exclusive ways to specify these views: manually or using a nib file. If you specify the views manually, you must implement the loadView method and use it to assign a root view object to the view property. If you specify views using a nib file, you must not override loadView but should instead create a nib file in Interface Builder and then initialize your view controller object using the initWithNibName:bundle: method.

Comment: I don't like InterfaceBuilder, i prefer building the interface per code.. and btw, you don't have to override loadview, you are able to.. most of the adjustments happen in viewdidload where you add subviews.. but this all is not related to my initial question :)